# Javascript - Problems interpretting array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a bot that interprets an array (exp table) and returns the exp difference between two levels.

I'm new to JavaScript still, so I'm sure it's something within my code, I have tried various combinations of array.find, array[x] and moving formula into variables. I just cannot seem to figure it out.

```
var xparray = [1, 0, 2, 300, 3, 900, 4, 2000, 5, 3700, 6, 6000, 7, 10200, 8, 16200, 9, 23550, 10, 33480, 11, 45280, 12, 60880, 13, 80480, 14, 104180, 15, 130580, 16, 161080, 17, 196480, 18, 236980, 19, 282680, 20, 333680, 21, 390280, 22, 454180, 23, 525580, 24, 604680, 25, 691780, 26, 786980, 27, 896780, 28, 1021580, 29, 1161780, 30, 1317680, 31, 1480180, 32, 1656080, 33, 1845680, 34, 2049180, 35, 2267080, 36, 2499400, 37, 2749300, 38, 3017100, 39, 3303300, 40, 3608200, 41, 3932200, 42, 4272400, 43, 4629200, 44, 5002900, 45, 5393700, 46, 5801900, 47, 6239500, 48, 6707000, 49, 7205000, 50, 7734000, 51, 8598000, 52, 9656400, 53, 10923600, 54, 12478800, 55, 14350800, 56, 16568400, 57, 19160400, 58, 22155600, 59, 25582800, 60, 29470800, 61, 33940800, 62, 38813800, 63, 44129800, 64, 49938800, 65, 56302800, 66, 63297800, 67, 71019800, 68, 79594800, 69, 89187800, 70, 100013800, 71, 112462800, 72, 126343800, 73, 141899800, 74, 159398400, 75, 179148400, 76, 201478400, 77, 226818400, 78, 255468400, 79, 288218400, 80, 325868400];


var tn = (String(message).length);
// !xp 40 60
var a = (String(message).length)-3;
var b = (String(message).length)-3;
var c = (String(message).length)-5;
var d = (String(message).length)-2;
var t0 = message.substring(b, a); //(-3,-3)
var t1 = message.substring(c, b); //(-5,-3)
var t2 = message.substring(d, tn); //(-2,0)
var na =  function(t0){return (t0*2)-1};
var nb =  function(t1){return (t1*2)-1};
var nc =  function(t2){return (t2*2)-1};
var T1 = xparray.find(function(element) {
    return element > t2});
var T2 = xparray.find(function(element) {
    return element > t0;
});
var T3 = xparray.find(function(element) {
    return element > t1;
});
var t3 = function(T1, T2, T3) {
    if (message.length = 7) {
        return T1 - T2;
    } else {
        return T1 - T3;
    }
};`
```

I expect this to pull values `40` and `60` from the end of the string `'!xp 40 60'`, interpret the array and pull the next value after `40 (3608200)` and the value after `60 (29470800)`, then preform a calculation to take the `40` value away from the `60` value `(29470800-3608200)`. So far I think the issue lies around the `T1`, `T2` and `T3` values as they are always returning 1, or the value in the array after `1 (300)`.

Comment: I would suggest you to make a 2 dimensional array out of it. `[[lvl, xp], [lvl, xp], ...]` would be easier to read and handle

Comment: what is `message`? please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @MauriceNino thank you, that makes more sense.

Comment: @Nina Scholz this is a bot for discord, so 'message' is the string from the user when triggering the bots if and case switch. for this function of the bot, the message would be "!xp 40 60"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### With one dimensional array:

You can just get the index of the **lvl** in the array with `indexOf` and then take the next value (which is the **xp** needed for that **lvl**). After that subtract the two and you are good to go:

```js
var xparray = [1, 0, 2, 300, 3, 900, 4, 2000, 5, 3700, 6, 6000, 7, 10200, 8, 16200, 9, 23550, 10, 33480, 11, 45280, 12, 60880, 13, 80480, 14, 104180, 15, 130580, 16, 161080, 17, 196480, 18, 236980, 19, 282680, 20, 333680, 21, 390280, 22, 454180, 23, 525580, 24, 604680, 25, 691780, 26, 786980, 27, 896780, 28, 1021580, 29, 1161780, 30, 1317680, 31, 1480180, 32, 1656080, 33, 1845680, 34, 2049180, 35, 2267080, 36, 2499400, 37, 2749300, 38, 3017100, 39, 3303300, 40, 3608200, 41, 3932200, 42, 4272400, 43, 4629200, 44, 5002900, 45, 5393700, 46, 5801900, 47, 6239500, 48, 6707000, 49, 7205000, 50, 7734000, 51, 8598000, 52, 9656400, 53, 10923600, 54, 12478800, 55, 14350800, 56, 16568400, 57, 19160400, 58, 22155600, 59, 25582800, 60, 29470800, 61, 33940800, 62, 38813800, 63, 44129800, 64, 49938800, 65, 56302800, 66, 63297800, 67, 71019800, 68, 79594800, 69, 89187800, 70, 100013800, 71, 112462800, 72, 126343800, 73, 141899800, 74, 159398400, 75, 179148400, 76, 201478400, 77, 226818400, 78, 255468400, 79, 288218400, 80, 325868400];

var message = '!xp 40 60';

var lvls = [parseInt(message.split(' ')[1]), parseInt(message.split(' ')[2])]; // Getting the lvls in question
lvls = lvls.map(l => xparray[xparray.indexOf(l)+1]); // Getting the xp values in question
console.log(lvls[1] - lvls[0]); // Substract xp values
```

#### With two-dimensional array (with use of a map to simplify):

Map that two dimensional array to a `Map` or use a `Map` in the first place. Then just get the correct **xp** value by the **lvl** key.

```js
var xparray = [[1, 0], [2, 300], [3, 900], [4, 2000], [5, 3700]];
var xpMap = new Map(xparray); // Map constructor takes the two dimensional array (key=lvl, value=xp)

var message = '!xp 2 3';

var lvls = [parseInt(message.split(' ')[1]), parseInt(message.split(' ')[2])]; // Getting the lvls in question

lvls = lvls.map(l => xpMap.get(l)); // Just map it by getting the value for the key

console.log(lvls[1] - lvls[0]); // Substract xp values
```

Comment: one of the best replies i've ever received, thank you! theres a few new bits in here that I didn't know existed, plus answers to problems I couldnt put into words initially like the array being a list without a key. Thank you for your time, you've really helped me out!